# Python list should be empty on class instance initialisation, but it's not. Why?

Tags: python, list, initialization

I would like to create instances of a class containing a list that's empty by default; instead of later setting this list to the final full list I would like to successively add items to it. Here's a piece of sample code illustrating this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class test:
    def __init__(self, lst=[], intg=0):
        self.lista   = lst
        self.integer = intg

name_dict = {}
counter   = 0

for name in ('Anne', 'Leo', 'Suzy'):
    counter += 1

    name_dict[name] = test()
    name_dict[name].integer += 1
    name_dict[name].lista.append(counter)

    print name, name_dict[name].integer, name_dict[name].lista
```

When I ran the above program I expected to get

> Anne 1 [1] 
>   Leo 1 [2] 
>   Suzy 1 [3]

as I assumed `lista` to always be initialised to an empty list.

What I got instead was this:

> Anne 1 [1] 
>   Leo 1 [1, 2] 
>   Suzy 1 [1, 2, 3]

If I replace `self.lista = lst` by `self.lista = []` it works fine, just like when I add the line `name_dict[name].lista = []` to the for loop.

Why is it that the contents of the previous objects' lists are retained, yet their values of `integer` aren't? I am rather new to Python, so it would be great if someone could point out to me where my thoughts/assumptions have gone astray.

Thanks a lot in advance for your replies.

Comment: @THC4k Thanks for the link; I did search for it, but I obviously picked the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to use a mutable object as a default value, as you do here:

```
def __init__(self, lst=[], intg=0):
     # ...
```

Change it to this:

```
def __init__(self, lst=None, intg=0):
     if lst is None:
         lst = []
     # ...
```

The reason that your version doesn't work is that the empty list is created just once when the function is defined, not every time the function is called.

In some Python implementations you can see the value of the default values of the function by inspecting the value of `func_defaults`:

```
print test.__init__.func_defaults
name_dict[name] = test()
# ...
```

Output:

```
([],)
Anne 1 [1]
([1],)
Leo 1 [1, 2]
([1, 2],)
Suzy 1 [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I like to declare it like this: lst = lst or []

Comment: @keegan3d: That's not quite the same. If the user provides an empty list your version will not use that list but instead create a new one, because an empty list is "falsy".

Answer (score 9):

The problem lies in this line:

```
def __init__(self, lst=[], intg=0):
```

You shouldn't use a list as a default argument. The first time `__init__` is called without `lst` specified the Python interpreter will define an empty list `[]`. Subsequent calls to the function will operate on the **same** list if `lst` is not specified, without declaring a new list. This causes weird problems.

You should instead use a default value of `None` and add a check at the beginning of the function:

```
def __init__(self, lst=None, intg=0):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
```

See [this post](http://garybernhardt.blogspot.com/2006/12/default-arguments-are-tricky.html) for further details. Quoting the post:

> Default arguments are evaluated at
>   function definition time, so they're
>   persistent across calls. This has some
>   interesting (and confusing) side
>   effects. An example:

```
>>> def foo(d=[]):
...     d.append('a')
...     return d
```

> If
>   you've not tried this before, you
>   probably expect foo to always return
>   `['a']`: it should start with an empty
>   list, append 'a' to it, and return.
>   Here's what it actually does:

```
>>> foo() ['a']
>>> foo() ['a', 'a']
>>> foo() ['a', 'a', 'a']
```

> This is because the default value for `d` is
>   allocated when the function is
>   created, not when it's called. Each
>   time the function is called, the value
>   is still hanging around from the last
>   call. This gets even weirder if you
>   throw threads into the mix. If two
>   different threads are executing the
>   function at the same time, and one of
>   them changes a default argument, they
>   both will see the change.
>
> Of course, all of this is only true if
>   the default argument's value is a
>   mutable type. If we change `foo` to be
>   defined as

```
>>> def foo2(d=0):
...     d += 1
...     return d
```

> then it will always return 1.
>   (The difference here is that in `foo2`,
>   the variable `d` is being reassigned,
>   while in `foo` its value was being
>   changed.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the default constructor argument. You should read this question to find answer to your question: [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 0):

Python evaluates the default arguments once at function definition:

```
def init_a():
    """Initialize a."""
    print("init_a")
    return 1


def test(a_parameter=init_a()):
    """A test function."""
    print("Execute test")

print("whatever")
test()
test()
```

gives

```
init_a
whatever
Execute test
Execute test
```

So your list gets defined once. You use the same list as before. This is why you should use the pattern

```
def a_function(a_parameter=None):  # Create 'None' once
    if a_parameter is None:
        a_parameter = []  # Create a new list - each time
```